# Default datastore instance inside dataflow job

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to call Google datastore inside dataflow job I am getting null instance

```
datastore = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be a credential issue. Could you try this,

```
Credentials credentials = context.getPipelineOptions().as(GcpOptions.class).getGcpCredential();

Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this code in the main function not inside dataflow Pipline.